# как узнать номер вхождения слова в словарь

Tags: python

```
name = {}
j = 1
    for i in range(int(input())):
    word = input()
    if word not in name.values():
        name[i] = word
        print('OK')
    else:
        print(word)
```

как узнать номер вхождения имени в словарь?
входные данные ниже

```
6
first
first
second
second
third
third
```

Comment: на второй `first` должно вывести `1`, а на второй `second` -- `2`?

Comment: в чем смысл делать словарь в данном случае, пишите в список, все будет просто. Захотите на выходе словарь - dict(enumerate(lst))

Comment: @gil9red ok first1 ok second1 ok third1

Comment: @splash58 по заданию нужно обязательно через словарь)

Comment: @skybea7, тогда просто `print(word + "1")`, но тогда непонятно зачем вести счет

Comment: @gil9red ну это же не единственный пример. может быть например: second second second. И тогда вывод уже будет ok second1 second2

Comment: @skybea7, а, теперь понятно :) Обновил ответ

Comment: @gil9red а как работает последняя строчка? имхо решение неверное, так у тебя везде OK на выводе будет, т.к ты не записываешь само слово в массив

Comment: @gil9red UPD. а нет, просто я дурак. тогда у меня вопросик.

Comment: @skybea7, пишите в комментарии под моим вопросом. Если мой ответ помог, проголосуйте и отметьте его

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
word_by_num = dict()

for _ in range(int(input())):
    word = input()
    if word not in word_by_num:
        word_by_num[word] = 0
        print('OK')
    else:
        word_by_num[word] += 1
        print(f'{word}{word_by_num[word]}')
```

Comment: в том то и прикол, что должен выводиться номер конкретного слова, а не всех сразу

Comment: @skybea7, это строка форматирования (f-строка), то, что указано в фигурных скобках `{}` будет подменено. Можно через конкантенацию строки сделать: `print("word" + str(word_by_num[word]))`, но мне кажется, что через форматирование более чисто получится

Comment: только у тебя опечатка. word не должно быть в кавычках -> print(word + str(word_by_num[word])) вместо print("word" + str(word_by_num[word]))

Comment: @skybea7, угу, опечатка )